# Composed Looks with custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am looking at [Responsive SharePoint](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com/) which is twitter bootstrap implementation of customer SharePoint 2013 master page and there are lots of page layouts available as well. What I want to do is to extend its SharePoint 2013 publishing master page to support composed looks. Can anybody tell how can I do that?

I already tried to google it but can not find how it works and what needs to be done if I want to do this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have gone through lots of msdn articles, and blogs and finally found some helpful links:

- [How to Edit the SharePoint 2013 Preview File for a Master Page](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/How-to-Edit-the-SharePoint-2013-Preview-File-for-a-Master-Page.aspx):
  This article shows how to add footer that supports composed looks. It was great to know this simple thing, to clear out concept.
- Amazing tool from microsoft [Color Palette Tool](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16806.color-palette-tool-sharepoint-2013.aspx): This article shows how you change design your own .spcolor file on the fly.

After reading a lot, finally starting to work on the actual task now...

Hope this will be helpful to you all looking for similar thing.